# How to avoid locking using lock_guard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard

> (constructor)
>   constructs a lock_guard, optionally locking the given mutex

What would be the way to avoid locking if it is optional?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the [`(constructor)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard) link to read more about it? It will tell you about the "optional" part and how to achieve it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No I hadn't. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to avoid having the `lock_guard` constructor lock the given `mutex` :

```
std::mutex mtx;
mtx.lock();
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx, std::adopt_lock);
```

The intention is to allow your `lock_guard` to take ownership of a `mutex` that you already locked.

From: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard

> explicit lock_guard( mutex_type& m );  (1)    (since C++11)
>       lock_guard( mutex_type& m, std::adopt_lock_t t );   (2)   (since C++11)
>       lock_guard( const lock_guard& ) = delete;   (3)   (since C++11)
>       Acquires ownership of the given mutex m.
>
> ```
> 1) Effectively calls m.lock(). The behavior is undefined if m is not a recursive mutex and the current thread already owns m.  
> 2) Acquires ownership of the mutex m without attempting to lock it.
> ```
>
> The behavior is undefined if the current thread does not own m.
>       3) Copy constructor is deleted.
>       The behavior is undefined if m is destroyed before the lock_guard object is.

Comment: Does `lock_guard(mutex_type& m, std::adopt_lock_t t);` check whether `m` is locked? In the case, it is not locked, does `lock_guard::~lock_guard()` skip the call of `unlock()`? I would expect this. However, I wonder it isn't mentioned in the cppreference doc. (An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for demo would be nice.)

Comment: @Scheff, *"The behavior is undefined if the current thread does not own m."* - here, "does not own" means "have not locked".  So you get undefined behavior if you pass an unlocked `mutex` to the `lockguard` constructor.

Comment: May be, I focused too much on the "optional". I understood the question as "How to use `lock_guard` optionally?" Reading it again I seem to have mis-understood this... (Sorry, my fault.)